# velor software ng2table nested object fetch in table

Tags: angular, datatable

```
public columns:Array<any> = [
    {
      title: 'Date Of Birth.', name: 'dob', sort: '',
       filtering: {filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by Dob'}
    },
    {
      title: 'Course', name: 'course',  sort: false
    }
  ];
```

This is my column description. I want to fetch course name on table. I can fetch course name but other functionality not work like pagination and filtering.

Comment: for more reference go to this link :: https://valor-software.com/ng2-table/

Comment: plane object working fine but nested object not work.